# Woocommerce how to show product list by attribute

Tags: woocommerce, attributes

I need to show list of product by their same attribute. I am not able to figure it out. Can any one please help me.

Also i need to create attribute page, I mean if Background color is attribute name and the terms are black, red, blue. i need to create attribute term page. how can i create that.